# Kotlin Arrays add element via With/let

Tags: arrays, kotlin, collections, kotlin-multiplatform

I have these code segments. I want to find the optimal solution and if it's possible some explanation why my 1st piece of code is broken. I have struggled with adding elements to the existing Array<>, without minimal external stuff. I tried with `+=' '.plus()`, and`.plusElement()`, and the only solution I found to work is by coping the current array to MutableList and then adding an element to it. After that, I convert it again to Array and return the right type Array<>. I am sure that there is a more elegant way, but I can't brainstorm it.

Question 2: I also tried to shorten the code with `with()`, `let{}` `run{}`, etc. to make  program.description.data.options as `it.` or `this.` instead of creation of new `var clone`

### Thank you in advance :)

I have some nested data classes for Serialization in Kotlin

*`FavouriteProgramCommandString` have property `val description: FavouriteProgram`

->
`FavouriteProgram` have `val data: FavouriteProgramDetails`

-> `FavouriteProgramDetails` have `var options: Array<FavouriteProgramOptions>,` 
*

```
data class FavouriteProgramDetails(
   @SerializedName(value = "key", alternate = ["featureKey"])
   val key: String,
   @SerializedName("options")
   var options: Array<FavouriteProgramOptions>,
)
```

**Broken code:**

```
    @JvmStatic
    fun getProgramDescriptionOfFavouritesWithDelayOption(
        program: FavouriteProgramCommandString,
        key: String,
        delayDuration: Double = 0.0,
    ): FavouriteProgram {

        with(program.description.data.options) {

            val nodeOption =
                firstOrNull { it.key == key }

            if (nodeOption != null) {
                this[this.indexOf(nodeOption)].value = delayDuration
            } else {
                this.plus(FavouriteProgramOptions(key, delayDuration)) // DONT'WORK
            }
        }
        return program.description // Absolutly the same array is returned.
    }
```

**Working code:**

```
    @JvmStatic
    fun getProgramDescriptionOfFavouritesWithDelayOptio2n(
        program: FavouriteProgramCommandString,
        key: String,
        delayDuration: Double = 0.0,
    ): FavouriteProgram {
        val clone = program.description.data.options.toMutableList()

        val nodeOption =
            clone.firstOrNull { it.key == key }

        if (nodeOption != null) {
            val index = clone.indexOf(nodeOption)
            clone[index].value = delayDuration
        } else {
            clone.add(FavouriteProgramOptions(key, delayDuration)) // It's working.
        }
        program.description.data.options = clone.toTypedArray() 

        return program.description // Return what is expected.
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason as to why the property is an `Array` and not a `List` (or mutable list)? The whole purpose of an array is that it is a fixed size sequential memory region. Your `FavouriteProgramOptions` object is obviously not a primitive as well, so there isn't even that optimisation to gain.

Comment: `plus()` is an operator function that appends the element to a NEW collection, and returns the result. It does NOT change the initial list provided. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-plus-minus.html

Comment: @Alex.T yes, because code basis is made of Array ( it's a heritage from previous devs, I asked myself the same question) These classes are used in a lot of places in an app, and I should change tons of linked functions params from Array to MutableList. (this can create bugs and stuff ) :/ Also one part of the project is with Java other with Kotlin. Thank you :)

Comment: @aSemy yes I checked that later , thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements cannot be added to or removed from an array. What you *can* do is create *new* arrays, with new elements, and this is what methods like `toTypedArray` and `plus` do. You need to *assign* this newly created array back to `program.description.data.options`, like you did in your working attempt:

```
program.description.data.options = clone.toTypedArray() 
                                ^^^
                       you assigned it here
```

Scope functions won't help you if you don't *assign* the newly created array!

```
program.description.data.options = with(program.description.data.options) {
    val nodeIndex = indexOfFirst { it.key == key }

    if (nodeIndex != -1) {
        this.also { this[nodeIndex].value = delayDuration }
    } else {
        this + FavouriteProgramOptions(key, delayDuration)
    }
}
```

Notice the assignment at the very beginning. `with` returns either `this`, with some changes, or a copy of `this`, but with one new element added. I've replaced `plus` with the operator form, which is more idiomatic, and avoided going through the array twice by using `indexOfFirst`.

In my opinion, it would be better for `program.description.data.options` to be a `MutableMap` instead. Then it would be easier to do this kind of operation. It'd be a simple `getOrPut`:

```
program.description.data.options.getOrPut(key) { FavouriteProgramOptions(key, delayDuration) }.value = delayDuration
```

Even using a `MutableList` instead would avoid making copies of the entire array each time you do this.